# Как пользоваться своим стационарным пк удалено

Tags: windows, виртуальная-машина, citrix

Большая просьба подсказать и рассказать как можно реализовать следующее:
У меня дома стоит персональный пк, там мощное железо, но оно простаивает.
Вопрос. Как реализовать подключение к моему пк удалено максимально эффективно.
Может через Citrix? Нахожу в сети ответы только решения для организации.
Может есть качественные системы по предоставлению удалённого доступа, но платные?
Насколько эффективно пользоваться Windows Virtual Desktop?

Answer (score 5):

Каждая Windows, начиная с Windows 2000, имеет механизм remote desktop connection.

Для включения этого механизманужно зайти в панель управления -> система -> удаленное управление -> разрешить удаленное управление для любой версии... (см. картинку)

При этом для пользователя, под котрым Вы будете логиниться, должен быть установлен пароль.

Когда это сделано -вы можете с соседнего компьютера залогиниться на свой, используя "подключение к удаленному компьютеру" - см картинку

Итак, это работает в пределах локальной сети. Попроьбуем перенести этот опыт в интернет. Для этого нужно сделать, чтобы порт 3389 Вашего  домашнего ПК был доступен в интернет.

Для этого нужно или настроить домашний роутрер - гуглить по словам "tcp port publishing" или "открыть порт в интернет". Обычно эта настройка в роутере находится в разделе "переадресация", "виртуальный сервер" и т.п.

При этом Вы должны знать свой внешний IP адрес, это можно выяснить, зайдя на домашнем компе на что то вроде http://myip.ru

Второй способ, если роутер настроить нельзя или не получилось - воспользоваться специализированным сервисом доступа, я знаю ngrok.com. На нем есть подробные инструкции по использованию.

Будьте осторожны и устанавливайте хороший пароль - ведь на Ваш компьютер после этого постараетесь попасть не только вы, но и множество ботов, котры охотятся за плохо защищенными системами.

Зато приятной особенностью этого метода является то, что доступ на комп можн получить не только с другой windows, но и с других операционных систем и мобильных устройств

Успехов вам!

[image: Настройки]

[image: Подключение]

Comment: Зачем для любой версии-то, это же "less secure"

Comment: @andreymal - согласен, но так как это проделывается в первый раз - пускай будет максимальная совместимость с клиентами. Потом можно и безопасности добавить, и на нестандартые порты перейти, и VPN поднять

Comment: Но, боюсь, до тех пор компьютер уже успеет начать майнить биткоины какому-нибудь китайцу (:

Comment: Выставлять винду голой задницей в интернеты - сомнительная затея. Лучше почитать маны по sstp\openvpn.